# Create a generic method to find largest value of a certain property in a list of objects

Tags: java, generics, groovy, java-8

I am using Groovy/Java to create a little side project to track footballers stats. I have a method that iterates over a list of Player objects and finds who has scored the most goals and kept the most clean sheets. At the moment the methods use the same code, I am trying to make one generic method but can't see how to do this as each property I want to find the maximum of will be different eg goals and clean sheets. Can anyone give me some pointers, I am new to generics, I tried to pass in a generic object but then couldn't work out how to then target a specific property on that object to count the highest value in the loop.

Here is my code

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0751dc3eae8f264e12ea4564f0e71dd2

```
@Override
Promise<Map<String, Double>> findPlayerWithMostMotms(List<Player> players) {
    Map<String, Integer> mostManOfTheMatches = [:]
    Integer currentlyMostManOfTheMatches = 0
    returnPlayerWithHighestAverageRating(
        players, mostManOfTheMatches, currentlyMostManOfTheMatches
    )
    return Promise.value(mostManOfTheMatches)
}

private
static List<Player> returnPlayerWithHighestAverageRating(List<Player> players, 
    Map<String, Integer> mostManOfTheMatches, Integer currentlyMostManOfTheMatches) {
    players.each {
        if (it.manOfTheMatches > currentlyMostManOfTheMatches) {
            mostManOfTheMatches.clear()
            mostManOfTheMatches.put(it.name, it.manOfTheMatches)
        }
    }
}

@Override
Promise<Map<String, Integer>> findMostCleanSheets(List<Player> players) {
    Map<String, Integer> mostCleanSheets = [:]
    Integer CurrentHighestValue = 0
    returnPlayerWithMostCleanSheets(players, mostCleanSheets, CurrentHighestValue)
    return Promise.value(mostCleanSheets)
}

private
static List<Player> returnPlayerWithMostCleanSheets(List<Player> players, 
    Map<String, Integer> mostCleanSheets, Integer CurrentHighestValue) {
    players.each {
        if (it.cleanSheets > CurrentHighestValue) {
            mostCleanSheets.clear()
            mostCleanSheets.put(it.name, it.cleanSheets)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: paste important code inside question for easier readability, also try to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: I’m not a Groovy programmer, but as far as I understand your code, on every occurrence of a player whose property exceeds the specified value, you are clearing the map and putting that element, so you don’t get a maximum element, but just an arbitrary element (the last one in iteration order) exceeding the specified old value, if there is at least one.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look into this [presentation](http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf) hold at the Java Forum in Stuttgart Germany last year.

Only a few slides use German language, 99% of the content is "English based" Java source code; like

```
collection .sort(
  Comparator
    .comparing(Person::getName)
    .thenComparing(Person::getId)
);
```

where "Comparator" is an example implementation that does what you are looking for - allowing to call a "selector" method (such as getName()) on some "data" class.

If you are into java8, you find a lot of material there to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing this, I am sure theres a nicer way to implement this.

```
      @Override
Promise<Map<String, ?>> findObjectwithLargestSpecificProperty(List<?> objects, String key, String propertyName) {
    Map<String, ?> highestKeyValuePair = [:]
    Integer currentHighestValue = 0
    returnObjectWithLargestSpecificPropertyValue(objects, highestKeyValuePair, currentHighestValue, key, propertyName)
    return Promise.value(highestKeyValuePair)
}


private
static List<?> returnObjectWithLargestSpecificPropertyValue(List<?> objects, Map<String, ?> highestKeyValuePair, Integer currentHighestValue, String key, String propertyName) {
    objects.each {
        if (it."${propertyName}" > currentHighestValue) {
            highestKeyValuePair.clear()
            highestKeyValuePair.put(it."${key}", it."${propertyName}")
        }
    }

}
```

I ended up passing through the property name and the key name I was looking for into a method.