# Sorting an ArrayList according to a criterion

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of *Subject* objects. These objects contain a String value (name) and an int value (number). I want to sort the list having the top number on first element and the bottom number at last.
How can I do that?
Thank you so much.

Comment: you need a comparator
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

Comment: @sirdan, you can read this [What is the difference between compare() and compareTo()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420223/what-is-the-difference-between-compare-and-compareto)

Comment: Can you help me a little more?

Comment: @sirdan What have you tried yet?

Comment: If you are looking for a Java8 solution ... then this answer here could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122597/create-a-generic-method-to-find-largest-value-of-a-certain-property-in-a-list-of/41122734#41122734

Comment: @GhostCat, what a nice solution!